# How to Implement Automatic Restart with Spring Boot on Docker When Source Code Changes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

I'm currently working on a project where I want to run a Spring Boot application on Docker with the feature of automatic restart when the source code changes. I have mounted the `src` directory inside the container using Docker Volumes. When I modify the code in the `src` directory from my local directory, the changes are reflected in the container's mounted files. However, the automatic restart feature I desire is not functioning as expected.

Here are some details about my setup:

- **Project GitHub URL**: https://github.com/redvelvet-fan/re-try-docker-demo.git
- **Current Behavior**: Changes in the `src` directory update the files in the container, but the application does not automatically restart.
- **Expected Behavior**: I would like the Spring Boot application to automatically restart whenever there are changes in the `src` directory files.

Could anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this functionality? I am looking for a solution where the Spring Boot application running inside a Docker container can automatically detect changes in the source code and restart itself.

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Java is a compiled language, so if the source code changes something would need to recompile and restart the application.  Do you have a setup that does this without Docker?

Comment: As far as I know, including developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools' in the dependencies of my build.gradle file is supposed to assist with restarting the application.

Is there anything else I need to set up in addition to this?
@DavidMaze